# Flutter migrate command not found

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project for Android & IOS. Today I started my laptop after a long time and tried to upgrade my project dependencies and add Null Safety too.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
sdk: ">=2.19.0 < 3.0.0"
```

I am on MAC OS and my project is in the partition I made in /Volumes/Data/Projects/myproject. When I try to run the **dart migrate** command, I am getting the following message.

```
Could not find a command named "migrate".

Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]

Global options:
-v, --verbose               Show additional command output.
    --version               Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics      Enable analytics.
    --disable-analytics     Disable analytics.
    --suppress-analytics    Disallow analytics for this `dart *` run without changing the analytics configuration.
    -h, --help                  Print this usage information.

 Available commands:  
 analyze              Analyze Dart code in a directory.
 compilation-server   Control the resident frontend compiler.
 compile              Compile Dart to various formats.
 create               Create a new Dart project.
 devtools             Open DevTools (optionally connecting to an existing application).
 doc                  Generate API documentation for Dart projects.
 fix                  Apply automated fixes to Dart source code.
 format               Idiomatically format Dart source code.
 info                 Show diagnostic information about the installed tooling.
 language-server      Start Dart's analysis server.
 pub                  Work with packages.
 run                  Run a Dart program.
 test                 Run tests for a project.
```

I noticed there is no **migrate** command in the **Available commands** list. I am able to run other commands from this folder like **dart fix**, **dart analyze** etc.

Right now I have to migrate all the files manually. If I could run a migrate tool that will be much more easier and faster for me.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The `dart migrate` command was removed in Dart 3.0.  If you need to migrate non-null-safe code, you either will need to migrate manually or downgrade to an earlier version of Flutter and Dart.

Comment: You mean to say downgrade the dart version and then use the tool to migrate and then upgrade the dart version back to the latest in yaml file?

Comment: You will need to downgrade your installed version of Dart to 2.19 or earlier to run `dart migrate`.  After that you can upgrade your installed version and use whatever version in your `pubspec.yaml` you want that supports null-safety (>=2.12). Also see https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration#removed-tools

Answer (score -1):

In pubspec.yaml replace the sdk with

```
environment:
   sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'
```

2.19 is already latest.

Comment: The latest version of Dart is 3.0.0.

Comment: Yeah but migrate is not there in dart 3. Downgrade dart and flutter to migrate it

Comment: Yes migrate is not there in 3. Does it mean in the future we will not be able to use the automated tool to migrate? I have already changed many files manually not scared to downgrade to 2.11.0.

Comment: -1 Simply changing the SDK version in the `pubspec.yaml` file will not help.  You need to downgrade the installed version of Dart.

Comment: @Sam The `migrate` tool was removed because Dart 3 has officially ceased any and all backward compatibility with non-null-safe code. The tool was added in Dart 2.12 with the initial release of null safety back in March of 2021. You cannot expect the Dart team to continue to provide support for a feature that has been on the deprecation path for over two years.

Comment: @KaushikChandru Simply decrementing the SDK version in the pubspec won't downgrade the installed version of Dart or Flutter.

Comment: It of course does work. By the way the steps given by flutter itself is the same.

`
The following steps might fix your problem:
1. Set the lower SDK constraint (in pubspec.yaml) to a version before 2.12.
2. Run `dart pub get`.
3. Try running `dart migrate` again.
`

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you have Dart 3.0.0 installed, make this change, then run `dart pub get`, you will get the error `"The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.11.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0'
or higher to enable null safety. The current Dart SDK (3.0.0) only supports null safety."`. All the pubspec `environment.sdk` field does is determine if the version of Dart you have installed is compatible with the project. It does NOT automatically install a compatible version of the SDK.

Comment: And that's not even getting into the version numbers you chose, of which there are two problems. First, `2.11.0` predates null safety, so this is already a dangerous version spread in which the installed version of Dart likely won't even have a `migrate` command available. Second, OP has Dart 3.0.0 installed, which means setting an upper bound of `<3.0.0` means their project is no longer compatible with their installed version of Dart and it will no longer compile.

Comment: I have flutter 3.7 installed and i am able to run dart migrate with the change in environment sdk

Comment: @KaushikChandru **And THERE'S the discrepancy.** You have Flutter 3.7, which includes Dart 2.19 and therefore has the `dart migrate` command. OP has Flutter 3.10 installed, which includes Dart 3.0 and therefore does **not** have that command. OP needs to downgrade to Flutter 3.7 in order to use the `dart migrate` command, and your answer doesn't do that.

Comment: I really appreciate KaushikChandru, @Abion47 and jamesdin. There was a need to downgrade my flutter by downloading the lower version of it which I did not want to do so. Finally I migrated all my code manually. Lesson learned: Don't wait until the water gets high. Again, thank you all of you.